# Creating PDF using itext without path

Tags: pdf, grails

I am developping a web Application in grails and trying to create a pdf document using itext.

it works fine when i got a path (local and on my server) but know i need to do it without creating it physically.

what i don't want: 
        PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(documentPDF,new FileOutputStream(mypath))

what i want :       //PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(documentPDF,new FileOutputStream())

so i tried using ObjectOutPutStream instead of using FileOutputStream but it doesn't work.

I hope you understood what i am expecting for.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a byte array output stream. Then you'll have the data

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(documentPDF, baos)

byte[] data = baos.toByteArray()
```

Comment: thx it works really fine , now a little question if you got a minute . can i still use pdfStamper to write in it even if i am using a baos?

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it meets your needs. I don't know anything about `pdfStamper`.